# Log4j - log ALL levels except ERROR

Tags: logging, log4j

Is there any way to achieve it? I mean what I want in my application is that it should log messages from all levels including debug and trace logs. The obvious way to achieve this is to set level to `ALL`. But I don't want to see any log of level `ERROR` in my log file.

My logger configuration is as follows:

```
log4j.category.com.serving=ALL, MFileLogger

log4j.appender.MFileLogger.File=/apps/logs/serving.log
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.MaxFileSize=250MB
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.MFileLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] SRV %p %C => %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [LevelMatchFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel) to achieve this. Something like this could work:

```
log4j.category.com.serving=ALL, MFileLogger

log4j.appender.MFileLogger.File=/apps/logs/serving.log
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.MaxFileSize=250MB
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.MFileLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.Append=true
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] SRV %p %C => %m%n

log4j.appender.MFileLogger.filter.ID=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.filter.ID.LevelToMatch=ERROR
log4j.appender.MFileLogger.filter.ID.AcceptOnMatch=false
```

If your log4j version predates [this patch](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46049) you may need to switch to an XML configuration (as stated in the wiki doc above) to make this work.